# R programming code correction

Tags: r

When i run the code below this is the error I get, "Error in if (mm[[j]] == mm[[j + 1]]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed "

Any ideas on how to fix this

```
m <- matrix(c(1:5,NA,7,7,NA),
nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=T)
print(m)
for ( i in 1:dim(m)[[1]] ) {
mm <- sort(m[i,],na.last=c(NA,NA,T)[[i]])
for ( j in 1:(length(mm)-1) ) {
if ( mm[[j]]==mm[[j+1]] ) {
cat(i,j,mm[[j]],fill=T)
}
}
}
```

Comment: `if()` does not work with a condition that evaluates to `NA`. As you have `NA` in the matrix, the loop creates conditions like `7 == NA`, which evaluates to `NA`.

Comment: Which means the following should work: `if ( mm[j] %in% mm[j+1] )`

Comment: I would also recommend using `seq_len(dim(m)[[1]])` in place of `1:dim(m)[[1]]` and `seq_len(length(mm) - 1)`.

Comment: Thanks LAP and Benjamin. Quick question for Benjamin, why use seq_len and not my original code. I am new to R and would greatly appreciate the insight.

Comment: You could also substitute `dim(m)[[1]]` with `nrow(m)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping `isTRUE()` around your `if`-condition:

```
for ( i in 1:dim(m)[[1]] ) {
  mm <- sort(m[i,],na.last=c(NA,NA,T)[[i]])
  for ( j in 1:(length(mm)-1) ) {
    if ( isTRUE(mm[[j]]==mm[[j+1]]) ) {
      cat(i,j,mm[[j]],fill=T)
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
3 1 7
```